# In python, when formatting of logger: %(user) gives an Key error. While python documentation have this as reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, keyerror

The configuration is like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='assignment.log', mode='a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)- %(user)8s -%(message)s')
fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fhandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

code which gives error:

```
logging.error('hello!')
logging.debug('This is a debug message')
logging.info('this is an info message')
logging.warning('tbllalfhldfhd, warning')
```

output error:

```
KeyError: 'user'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'user'
```

The python documentation having this as reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter

Comment: `%(user)` does not appear in the documentation section you linked.

Answer (score 2):

The python documentation has user as an example of a user-defined format:

```
logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', **extra=d**)
```

emphasis mine. If you want to use the construct, you'll have to send your own dictionary as the extra parameter, e.g.:

```
logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra={"user": "Sarthak"})
```

Answer (score 1):

`%(user)` does not appear in the documentation section you linked. It only appears in documentation about the `extra` keyword certain functions take. For example, [`logging.debug`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug) and similar calls:

> The third optional keyword argument is extra which can be used to pass
> a dictionary which is used to populate the `__dict__` of the LogRecord
> created for the logging event with user-defined attributes. These
> custom attributes can then be used as you like. For example, they
> could be incorporated into logged messages. For example:
>
> ```
> FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
> logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
> d = {'clientip': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'fbloggs'}
> logging.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)
> ```

Here, the `%(user)` in the format refers to a `user` key in an `extra` dict provided in the `logging.warning` call. If you do not provide an `extra` dict, there is no `user` value to log.